# How to have a default radio button checked in Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, radio-button

I have a radio button built using Ruby as in below

```
      <p>Which design do you prefer to use? </p>
      <% [ 'Design 1', 'Design 2', 'Design 3', 'Design 4', 'Design 5' ].each do |theme| %>
          <br><%= radio_button_tag 'theme', theme, @theme == theme %>
          <%= label_tag "theme_#{theme}", theme.humanize %>
      <% end %>
```

I want to ensure that the first element (aka Design 1) is always checked by default unless user choses some other design.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this: Pass in `checked` to check the item

```
<%= radio_button_tag 'theme', theme, checked: @theme.FIELD_NAME == 'design' %>
```

See here for details http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper/radio_button_tag

Answering your comment:

> Ahmm I dont understand? :( So `<%= radio_button_tag 'theme', theme %>`
>    becomes <%= radio_button_tag 'theme', theme, checked:
>   @theme.FIELD_NAME == 'design' %> ?? But this throws an error? I just
>   want the first radio button element to be selected by default –

`FIELD_NAME` is the name of the column on your Model. To just check the first item you can try this: Just add the `checked: true` keyword

```
<%= radio_button_tag 'theme', theme, @theme == theme, checked: true %>
```

Ok so you need to do the following:

```
<% [ 'Design 1', 'Design 2', 'Design 3', 'Design 4', 'Design 5' ].each_with_index do |theme, i| %>
  <% if i == 0 %>
      <br><%= radio_button_tag 'theme', theme, @theme == theme, checked: true %>
  <% else %>
      <br><%= radio_button_tag 'theme', theme, @theme == theme %>
  <% end %>
  <%= label_tag "theme_#{theme}", theme.humanize %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Ahmm I dont understand? :( So ` <%= radio_button_tag 'theme', theme %> ` becomes `<%= radio_button_tag 'theme', theme, checked: @theme.FIELD_NAME == 'design' %>`  ?? But this throws an error? I just want the first radio button element to be selected by default

Comment: Here in your case, use this: `<%= radio_button_tag 'theme', theme, @theme == theme, checked: true %>` Remember to upvote and check answers.

Comment: Hi, Thanks. All the elements stays checked=checked in the source code and the last element checked . I do not want all element to have checked=checked. :(

Comment: `@theme == theme, checked: true` should just be `true`

Comment: In fact, the code can be simplified to just `<% [ 'Design 1', 'Design 2', 'Design 3', 'Design 4', 'Design 5' ].each_with_index do |theme, i| %>
  <br><%= radio_button_tag 'theme', theme, @theme == theme || i == 0 %>
  <%= label_tag "theme_#{theme}", theme.humanize %>
<% end %>`